# Yii session live time issue

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii

I have Yii application and inside there is a module 'admin', which requires auth. And so it has model 'LoginForm' - generated by yii, where there is a line:

```
$duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0;
```

So, if i check 'remember me' checkbox the session should live for 30 days, but it actually lives for about 90 minutes (approx.) anyway. Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Did you check if the cookie is stored in your browser?

Comment: Yes, [here it is](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17309724/cookie.png)

Comment: Probably duplicated: [Yii users being logged out after 15-30 minutes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859333/yii-users-being-logged-out-after-15-30-minutes-despite-session-timeouts-being-se)

Comment: I have this code after:Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);

Comment: What is the value of `session.gc_maxlifetime`? It needs to be at least as large as the session duration.

Comment: Where can I check this?

Comment: Look at `php.ini` for `gc_maxlifetime` and make sure that `authTimeout` of `CWebUser` has been also set properly in `config/main.php`: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#authTimeout-detail

Comment: `authTimeout` of `CWebUser` I set to 3600*24*30.
php.ini:
    `session.use_only_cookies = 1`
    `session.cookie_lifetime = 0`
    `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440`
Shold I set session.gc_maxlifetime to 3600*24*30?